# Electron Atom APP : Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined

Tags: electron

This is electron desktop app. While creating windows installer using this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-windows-installer via gulp, i am getting following error message.

gulp create-windows-installer

Using gulpfile D:\bala\electron\poc\installer\app4\gulpfile.js
Starting 'create-windows-installer'...
'create-windows-installer' errored after 4.49 s

Error: Command failed: D:\bala\electron\poc\installer\app4\node_modul
es\electron-windows-installer\vendor\nuget.exe 
pack C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Loca
l\Temp\squirrel-installer-116318-5484-1nobhq\app.nuspec

-BasePath D:\bala\electr
on\poc\installer\app4\dist\app-win32-ia32 -OutputDirectory C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppDa
ta\Local\Temp\squirrel-installer-116318-5484-1nobhq

-NoDefaultExcludes
Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

```
at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:213:12)
at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:827:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
```

I am using Windows 7, 32bit. Any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution by adding "iconUrl" attribute in gulp tasker with icon path value. i.e, "https://www.domain.com/image.ico". 
NOTE: icon image must be external path like "http" or "https".