# Electron-Installer-Windows : Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined

Tags: electron

I am trying to create the .exe file in order to be able to run the application that I fixed on windows environment.
Firstly, I use the command:

```
electron-packager . app --platform win32 --arch x64 --out dist/
```

which it creates the dist folder as described here :
    https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager
Finally, I run the command :

```
electron-installer-windows --src ./dist/app-win32-x64 --config config.json/
```

(as described here: 
    https://github.com/unindented/electron-installer-windows).
The config.json file contains : 

    `{
      "authors": ["auth"],
      "dest": "/dist/installers/"
    }`

`Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.`

I have also seen this question : [Electron Atom APP : Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36696430/electron-atom-app-invalid-uri-the-format-of-the-uri-could-not-be-determined)
but it seems it does not work.
Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: I'having the same issue. I've tryed applying this issue [1](https://github.com/electron/grunt-electron-installer/issues/74) but it didn't work out for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this error is due to an incorrect path when trying to create the installer.

I still haven't been able to validate this, but if you have node_modules folder with its nested dependencies and you have **paths longer than 260 characters** that may just be the problem.

If I'm able to comfirm this or get a solution I'll post it here.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue and it was resolved by setting the proper "url" field for the author in the package.json file.

Comment: I was also having this issue and fixed it by changing all urls to absolute paths